# How to convert keys in a Map to lower case?

Tags: scala, dictionary, collections

I have a map where the key is a String and I need to change every key to lower case before work with this map.

How can I do it in Scala? I was thinking something like:

```
var newMap = scala.collection.mutable.Map[String, String]()
data.foreach(d => newMap +=(d._1.toLowerCase -> d._2))
```

What is the best approach for it? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem here is that you're trying to add the lower-cased keys to the mutable `Map`, which is just going to pile additional keys into it. It would be better to just use a strict `map` here, rather than a side-effecting function.

```
val data = scala.collection.mutable.Map[String, String]("A" -> "1", "Bb" -> "aaa")
val newData = data.map { case (key, value) => key.toLowerCase -> value }
```

If you *really* want to do it in a mutable way, then you have to remove the old keys.

```
data.foreach { case (key, value) =>
    data -= key
    data += key.toLowerCase -> value
}

scala> data
res79: scala.collection.mutable.Map[String,String] = Map(bb -> aaa, a -> 1)
```

Comment: Doing it the mutable way as you show is a bit dodgy because you are modifying the map as you are iterating it. Effectively this means that foreach's body can be executed several times (you can easily verify it by adding a log). In this particular case this does not affect the result because converting to lowercase is idempotent, but that's not a good habit to have and will break for any non idempotent operation.

Comment: Good point. I prefer to avoid the mutable map entirely (clearly it could have bitten me).

Comment: BTW you can shorten the code slightly by using `transform` instead: `data.transform{ (key, _) => key.toLowerCase }`

Answer (score 4):

Your approach would work, but in general in Scala for this kind of transformation the immutable variants of the collections are preferred.

You can use the `map` method of the `Map` class with the following one liner:

```
val m = Map("a"->"A", "B"->"b1", "b"->"B2", "C"->"c")
m.map(e=>(e._1.toLowerCase,e._2))
```