# How to convert a map's keys from String to Int?

Tags: scala

This is my initial RDD output

```
scala> results
scala.collection.Map[String,Long] = Map(4.5 -> 1534824, 0.5 -> 239125, 3.0 -> 4291193, 3.5 -> 2200156, 2.0 -> 1430997, 1.5 -> 279252, 4.0 -> 5561926, 
rating -> 1, 1.0 -> 680732, 2.5 -> 883398, 5.0 -> 2898660)
```

I am removing a string Key to keep only numbers.

```
scala> val resultsInt = results.filterKeys(_ != "rating")
resultsInt: scala.collection.Map[String,Long] = Map(4.5 -> 1534824, 0.5 -> 239125, 3.0 -> 4291193, 3.5 -> 2200156, 2.0 -> 1430997, 1.5 -> 279252, 4.0 -> 5561926, 1.0 -> 680732, 2.5 -> 883398, 5.0 -> 2898660)
```

Sorting the RDD based on values, it gives expected output, but I would like to convert the key from String to int before sorting to get consistent output.

```
scala> val sortedOut2 = resultsInt.toSeq.sortBy(_._1)
sortedOut2: Seq[(String, Long)] = ArrayBuffer((0.5,239125), (1.0,680732), (1.5,279252), (2.0,1430997), (2.5,883398), (3.0,4291193), (3.5,2200156), (4.0,5561926), (4.5,1534824), (5.0,2898660))
```

I am new to Scala and just started writing my Spark program. Please let me know some insights to convert the key of Map object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your sample output, I suppose you meant converting the key to `Double`?

```
val results: scala.collection.Map[String, Long] = Map(
  "4.5" -> 1534824, "0.5" -> 239125, "3.0" -> 4291193, "3.5" -> 2200156,
  "2.0" -> 1430997, "1.5" -> 279252, "4.0" -> 5561926, "rating" -> 1,
  "1.0" -> 680732, "2.5" -> 883398, "5.0" -> 2898660
)

results.filterKeys(_ != "rating").
  map{ case(k, v) => (k.toDouble, v) }.
  toSeq.sortBy(_._1)

res1: Seq[(Double, Long)] = ArrayBuffer((0.5,239125), (1.0,680732), (1.5,279252), (2.0,1430997),
   (2.5,883398), (3.0,4291193), (3.5,2200156), (4.0,5561926), (4.5,1534824), (5.0,2898660))
```

Answer (score 0):

To map between different type, you just need to use map Spark/Scala operator.

You can check the syntax from here 
[Convert a Map[String, String] to Map[String, Int] in Scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22723965/convert-a-mapstring-string-to-mapstring-int-in-scala)

The same method can be used with Spark and Scala.

Answer (score 0):

please see [Scala - Convert keys from a Map to lower case?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29369984/scala-convert-keys-from-a-map-to-lower-case)

the approach should be similar,

```
case class row (id: String, value:String)

val rddData = sc.parallelize(Seq(row("1", "hello world"), row("2", "hello there")))

rddData.map{
     currentRow => (currentRow.id.toInt, currentRow.value)}
//scala> org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(Int, String)]
```

even if you didn't define a case class for the structure of the rdd and you used something like Tuple2 instead, you can just write

```
currentRow._1.toInt // instead of currentRow.id.toInt
```

please research on casting for information (when converting from String to Int), there's a few ways to go about that

hope this helps! good luck :)

Answer (score 0):

Distilling your `RDD` into a `Map` is legal, but it defeats the purpose of using Spark in the first place. If you are operating at scale, your current approach renders the `RDD` meaningless. If you aren't, then you can just do Scala collection manipulation as you suggest, but then why bother with the overhead of Spark at all?

I would instead operate at the `DataFrame` level of abstraction and transform that `String` column into a `Double` like this:

```
import sparkSession.implicits._

dataFrame
   .select("key", "value")
   .withColumn("key", 'key.cast(DoubleType))
```

And this is of course assuming that Spark didn't recognize the `key` as a `Double` already after setting the `inferSchema` to `true` on initial data ingest.

Answer (score -1):

If you are trying to filter out the key being non-number, you may just do the following:

```
import scala.util.{Try,Success,Failure}

(results map { case (k,v) => Try (k.toFloat) match {
  case Success(x) => Some((x,v))
  case Failure(_) => None
}}).flatten

res1: Iterable[(Float, Long)] = List((4.5,1534824), (0.5,239125), (3.0,4291193), (3.5,2200156), (2.0,1430997), (1.5,279252), (4.0,5561926), (1.0,680732), (2.5,883398), (5.0,2898660))
```